# How could I monitor the CPUs' efficiencies of a Slurm job?

Tags: multithreading, slurm, hpc

I developed a Python script that enables multiple-threads. I sent my code to Slurm. I would like to verify if the multiple threads work well.
Therefore I want to monitor the real-time CPUs' usage. Is there any command can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Most clusters allow logins to nodes if the user has a job running on it. So, just ssh to the node that is running your job, and run [`top(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html)

If your code is multithreaded, the value in the `%CPU` column should be greater than 100%. Each thread, if it is fully busy, can consume up to 100% CPU (i.e. all the cycles on a single CPU core). So, N threads can consume up to N*100%.